# OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener not getting called

Tags: android

I have created a `PreferenceActivity` and I have implemented [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html).

By using `PreferenceScreen` for `Preferences`, the [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) is not getting called.

Why is OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() not getting called?

MyPreferenceActivity.java

```
package com.example.sms_reader;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyPreferenceActivity 
         extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
  SharedPreferences prefs;
  MyPreferenceActivity listener;

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
  }


  @Override
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences preferences,
                                        String key) {
    if(key == "RESET") {  
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                     "RESET Values changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Log.d("on shared preference gets a call","on shared preference gets a call" ); 
      Boolean b = preferences.getBoolean("reset", false);
      Log.d("reset value", String.valueOf(b)); 

      if (b == true) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                     "RESET Values changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        preferences.edit().clear().commit();
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getApplicationContext(), R.xml.preferences, true);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        startActivity(intent);               
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not getting called or just does not find "RESET" key?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `if` condition like this:

```
if (key.equals("RESET")) {
```

If it still doesn't work then put a breakpoint on it (or a log message right in front) to see if execution really passes there or not.